# WCF - Error generating flat WSDL when versioning service using namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wsdl, versioning

I have a WCF Web Service which I want to version. In this case, I have a certain operation `MyOperation` that changes type signature and changes semantically enough to merit a new major version. I want the client to, if possible, only change the namespace from *v1* to *v2* and be able to use the new operation.

I use strict versioning and define the service contract like so (I'm using placeholder names):

```
[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/myService/v1", Name = "MyOpResponse")]
public class MyOpResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/myService/v1")]
public interface IMyService
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "MyOperation")]
    MyOpResponse MyOperation(string parameter);

    [OperationContract(Name = "MyOtherOperation")]
    int MyOtherOperation(int parameter);
}

[DataContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/myService/v2", Name = "MyOpResponse")]
public class MyOpResponse_v2
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://mycompany.com/myService/v2")]
public interface IMyService_v2
{
    [OperationContract(Name = "MyOperation")]
    MyOpResponse_v2 MyOperation_v2(string parameter);

    [OperationContract(Name = "MyOtherOperation")]
    int MyOtherOperation(int parameter);
}
```

I want to change `MyOperation` to a new version with a new return type, but have other operations remain the same (like `MyOtherOperation`)

The service definition is as follows (with a default implementation):

```
public class MyService : IMyService, IMyService_v2
{
    public MyOpResponse_v2 MyOperation_v2(string parameter)
    {
        return new MyOpResponse_v2 { Value = parameter.Length };
    }

    public int MyOtherOperation(int parameter)
    {
        return parameter + 100;
    }

    public MyOpResponse MyOperation(string parameter)
    {
        return new MyOpResponse { Value = parameter };
    }
}
```

And in my *Web.config* I have the following definitions:

```
<behaviors>
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyEndpointBehavior" />
    </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>

<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
        <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
        <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
        <serviceSecurityAudit auditLogLocation="Application" suppressAuditFailure="true" serviceAuthorizationAuditLevel="Failure" messageAuthenticationAuditLevel="Failure" />
        <aspNetCompatibilityRequirementsBehavior requirementsMode="Allowed" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>

<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MyBinding">
            <security mode="None" />
        </binding>
    </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>

<service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="MyCompany.MyService">
    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" name="MyService" contract="MyCompany.IMyService" />

    <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyEndpointBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" name="MyService_v2" contract="MyCompany.IMyService_v2" />
</service>
```

When I publish the service, the generated WSDL in http://localhost/MyService.svc?wsdl seems correct (I remove namespaces and definitions that are not really relevant):

```
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:i1="http://mycompany.com/myService/v2" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:i0="http://mycompany.com/myService/v1" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" name="MyService" targetNamespace="http://mycompany.com/myService/v2">
    <wsdl:binding name="MyService" type="i0:IMyService">
    ...
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:binding name="MyService_v2" type="i1:IMyService_v2">
    ...
    </wsdl:binding>

    <wsdl:service name="MyService">
        <wsdl:port name="MyService" binding="tns:MyService">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/MyService.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="MyService_v2" binding="tns:MyService_v2">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost/MyService.svc"/>
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

However, if I try to generate the flat WSDL file with http://localhost/MyService.svc?singleWsdl I get this error:

```
System.NotSupportedException: A single WSDL document could not be generated for this service. Multiple service contract namespaces were found (http://mycompany.com/myService/v1, http://mycompany.com/myService/v2). Ensure that all your service contracts have the same namespace.
```

With the above solution, I have both versions of my service hosted at http://localhost/MyService.svc . If the client wants to call v1, he only needs to use the namespace *http://mycompany.com/myService/v1*; and if he wants to change to the v2 version he only needs to change the namespace to http://mycompany.com/myService/v2. The WSDL file with imports is generated correctly, but only the flat WSDL file is generated incorrectly. I need to generate the flat WSDL to provide to a third party.

Is it possible to have the above versioning system and still generate the flat WSDL correctly with ?singleWSDL?

If not, what is the better alternative?

Comment: A WSDL has a root element with an attribute that defines the described service's namespace, so you cannot use two service namespaces in one WSDL. Perhaps you can combine the resulting WSDLs and XSDs into one WSDL per service, containing its own type definitions.

Comment: So it's impossible to use namespace-based versioning in the same service/WSDL? Every major (i.e breaking) version *must* be in a new service?

Comment: Consider the first ?wsdl as full-featured way of generating WSDL according to WCF (strict) versioning strategies with more contracts in single service. This is the default (and usual) way to go, if you want to use this versioning. The second ?singleWsdl can be used when there's only SINGLE root namespace as @CodeCaster already pointed out. Or single contract in terms of your versioning. That's why it's called singleWSDL :)